# Setting language read access for endusers

Tags: security, multilingual, language-fallback

We have followed this excellent guide: https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2010/06/30/setting-up-security-on-languages-in-sitecore-6/ for setting up security in the Sitecore client for our Sitecore editors.

However, now we need to set security for our end users (website users). I thought would be done in a similar way, but according to Sitecores own documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/81/sitecore-experience-platform/en/the-access-rights.html `Language read` does not affect the website. This is for Sitecore 9.2.

Our website has "requirelogin" set, so currently all users are required to signin. During signin, we create a virtual user and add an "extranet\xyz" role to that virtual user.

How do we allow e.g. french users to only see the french content and not content below `/en-gb`?

Comment: Currently, I am looking at replacing the SecurityCheck processor, with a custom that includes the language read check, I was just hoping something out of the box was available